# How can I change the path for root permanently in solaris sparc?

Tags: path, solaris, root, sparc

I have edited /etc/profile but the path only gets changed for normal users whereas the change does not reflect for root, how can I make it such that the path also gets changed for root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Solaris, regular users and root default PATH are defined in `/etc/default/login` and `/etc/default/su` in the PATH & SUPATH variables.

Comment: so does that mean I would have to include 
PATH=$PATH:/new/path
export PATH
inside /etc/default/su?

Comment: No. /etc/default/su isn't a shell script but a file defining initial settings whatever the shell is. $PATH would mean nothing here. Of course, further scripts like /etc/profile and $HOME/.profile can alter this initial setting.

Answer (score 0):

root uses a different shell from everybody else; or very definitely should: /bin/sh
If you used bash/ksh syntax:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/new/path1:/new/path2
```

...will not work.

```
PATH=${PATH}:/new/path1:/new/path2
export PATH
```

This fits /bin/sh syntax